# Webservice Parsing using Afnetworking stopped working

Tags: ios, http, https, afnetworking, nsurlsession

********************** ***Update***  **********************

upon initial analysis i found that the website with https is not opening in iPhone,iPad or iPod if i tried hitting the website from app with just http i am able to load the JSON .

It seems like the concern is with HTTPS and i am able to get the DATA from HTTP URL

> Simply
>
> **HTTPS**://www.xzzx.xzzx.com/app/zxzx/zx.php/zx_xz
>   ---->   no response
>
> **HTTP**://www.xzzx.xzzx.com/app/zxzx/zx.php/zx_xz,
>   ---->    valid JSON

i cross checked the api as from my end Request is being sent on backend and valid JSON gets generated

i did this all by adding a mail function in the api file for each request made from my app is sent to me on mail with  intended response and request paramter .BUT in xcode i always getting Response null .Even it is not returning any kind of error or invalid content received in app.

********************** ***Original Question*** **********************

Our website migrated to new server.Now the previous working web-services are not working in iOS But are working FINE in POSTMAN .Below is my implementation

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlWithAction];
NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"content-type": @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                           @"cache-control": @"no-cache",
                           @"web-token": @"eb7524958-aghf-31fd8-00e4-e887df00035c"};

NSString *parmetersToPost=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",postDataStr,appCommonParamters ];
NSMutableData *postData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[parmetersToPost   dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:3000.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[[manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:responseBlock] resume];
```

i am getting the following error

> 2017-07-06 15:20:45.538 DE[4013:1659696] Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "cannot parse response"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.xzzx.xzzx.com/app/zxzx/zx.php/zx_xz,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.xzzx.xzzx.com/app/zxzx/zx.php/zx_xz,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=cannot parse response,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x19266180 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1017 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSErrorPeerAddressKey={length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes =
>   0x100201bb4834d0520000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1}}}

How can i troubleshoot the concern ,If i tried to check the webservices response on postman response is showing .

In Postman there is code section to make web request .i tried using postmen code but no luck and still getting the same error.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The concern was solved as the issue was due to multiple factors ,all
>   from server side not from the app side as the website previously was
>   hosted on HTTP 1.1 but new server was using HTTP 2.0 and HTTP/2 in
>   Apache is  not configure correctly .reconfiguration for HTTP/2 in
>   Apache and valid SSl on the subdomains fixed the concern

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with adding ATS flag in project info.plist file for https .May be your server does not have SSL/TLS certificate installed.

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: as per my knowledge ATS flag when Set TURE  is to load the HTTP request  and BTW it is already added and is set TRUE as i Am loading some HTTP request

Comment: Then it could be issue with response json from server.Postman does not have restriction like mobile platform.I would suggest to analyze your request response with tcpdump. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1176/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10001707-CH1-SECGETTINGSTARTEDWITHTCPDUMP

Comment: I was facing some issue due to self-signed certificates in my app . It worked with setting security policy to allow any type of certificate.
        AFSecurityPolicy *sec=[[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
        [sec setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
        requestOperation.securityPolicy=sec;